# Why do we use multiple convolutions in CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

Let's say if we have non-linear ReLU in between two or more convolutional layers ( Conv relu Conv relu Conv relu max pool) what different information I will get as compared to using a single convolutional layer ( Conv relu max pool).

How does it help?

Comment: If you don't have a ReLU (or any other non-linear operation) between the two (or more) Conv layers,  they can be collapsed into a single Conv.  I don't think it's possible if the non-linear operation is interposed.

Comment: My question is regarding using multiple conv without reducing the size before pooling